# open rails app from github in c9 IDE

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How can I open my rails application using google cloud9 cloud service. https://ide.c9.io IDE? What steps do I need to take? I have already copied and pasted application folder in IDE but when I run "bundle exec rails server -b $IP -p $PORT" it doesn't show anything.

Comment: It depends... there should be a _readme_ file with instructions or guidance for how to set everything up. And from experience running an existing rails app in c9 can add extra complications.

Comment: It's a very basic app. There is no info in README.txt

Comment: What's the github link?

Comment: https://github.com/RichIsOnRails/CalendarExample

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When starting a new workspace, you have an option to clone from a github repository, there is a box that states `Clone from Git or Mecurial URL`. Simply fill in the appropriate url from your git repo, choose ruby on rails for the template, and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 1):

I have been using c9 for quite a long time.

This is how to start(assuming you already checked out the code :))..

```
 1. open new terminal
 2. run /bin/bash --login
 3. rvm use 2.2.2@myapp ---if using rvm 
 4. sudo /etc/init.d/postgresql start  -- start postgres server if using
```

if you still dont have rails ,install using **Ruby version manager** AKA [**rvm**](https://rvm.io/rvm/basics)..its very easy.

Now run..`rails s -b $IP -p $PORT`.
So when you server has started successfully,hit the application on the browser using...`https://<your-workspace-name>-<your username for git>.c9users.io/`..
for me its like...[geophotos-mike1011.c9users.io](http://geophotos-mike1011.c9users.io)

you may also click top right button **Preview** ...to preview your app inside your window.

Moreover,you can customise your app setting to be public/private and many more things to do..if you are a premium user :)

Hope it helps.

Comment: It doesn't work:`dalyvis:~/workspace/CalendarExample-master $ rails s -b $IP -p $PORT
bash: rails: command not found`

Comment: answer updated with other commands...kindly check and reply :)

Comment: Same issue: `bash: rails: command not found`. Did you manage to run this app on your side? github.com/RichIsOnRails/CalendarExample

Comment: install rails using rvm..added in my answer too :0

Comment: what do you get after running rails -v on the terminal ?

Comment: My mistake. My development environment was "rails tutorial" instead of "ruby". Now, how should I copy and run existing app project in this environment? I have this application folder: https://github.com/RichIsOnRails/CalendarExample/blob/master/

Comment: create new app on c9 with Ruby and then checkout.then setup the DB and run rake db:migrate...well check out the tutorial--> https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-setup-ruby-on-rails-with-postgres

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, one of the things you need to note is to add your shh github fingerprint to c9, which will enable you to push to GitHub from c9 afterwards. c9 should put you through the necessary step.

Secondly, follow RailsCasts Tutorial on how to contribute to open source http://railscasts.com/episodes/300-contributing-to-open-source.

I think that's about all you need to make your problem solved.